# How to append JSON object

Tags: javascript

I have data in localStorage set with user details like this

```
{"name":"aa","email":"aa@aa.aa","password":"aaaa","confirm_password":"aaaa"}
```

and another one like

```
{"otp":"1235"}
```

Now, I want to retrieve this as an single object like this

```
{"name":"aa","email":"aa@aa.aa","password":"aaaa","confirm_password":"aaaa","otp":"1235"}
```

Please help. Thanks.

Comment: How are you reading them out of a local storage and assigning them to vars?

Comment: Use object destructuring

Comment: `Object.assign(obj1, obj2);`  or `Object.assign({}, obj1, obj2); `  (I consider you casted the localstorage string to a json object)

Comment: With their keys like localStorage.getItem('userData'); & for another localStorage.getItem('otp');

Answer (score 0):

Use object destructuring:

```js
const obj1 = JSON.parse('{"name":"aa","email":"aa@aa.aa","password":"aaaa","confirm_password":"aaaa"}');
const obj2 = JSON.parse('{"otp":"1235"}');
const obj3 = { ...obj1, ...obj2 };

console.log(obj3);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
jsonArray1 = {"name":"aa","email":"aa@aa.aa","password":"aaaa","confirm_password":"aaaa"};
jsonArray2 = {"otp":"1235"};
 Object.assign(jsonArray1, jsonArray2);
```